# drag-drop to multiple elemnts issue

Tags: javascript, css, html, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to implement a drag-drop scenario.

A problem that I'm having is that I need to drop an element on an outer div but the event fires on the inner div.

Here is a codepen to demonstrate my problem:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdvboR

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .dropDiv {
        height: 100px;
        width: 200px;
        border: 1px solid black;
      }

      .innerDiv {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        border-right: 1px solid black;
      }


      .drag {
        border: 1px solid green;
      }

      .drop {
        border: 1px solid red;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span id="text" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" ondragend="dragend(event)" class="">Drag Text</span>

    <br>
    <br>

    To Here:
    <div class="dropDiv" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragenter="dragenter(event)" ondragleave="dragleave(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      <div class="innerDiv"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function allowDrop(ev) {
          ev.preventDefault();
      }
      function drag(ev) {
          $(ev.target).addClass('drag');
          ev.dataTransfer.setData('text', ev.target.id);
      }
      function dragenter(ev) {
          $(ev.target).addClass('drop');
      }
      function dragleave(ev) {
          $(ev.target).removeClass('drop');
      }
      function dragend(ev) {
          $(ev.target).removeClass('drag');
      }
      function drop(ev) {
          ev.preventDefault();
          var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData('text');
          ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
          $(ev.target).removeClass('drop');
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I need that whenever the dragged element is in the outer div the border will be red. but when the mouse is over the inner div, only the inner div's border is red.

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Go through this example

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Droppable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #draggable { width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; }
  #droppable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px; }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
          .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
          .find( "p" )
            .html( "Dropped!" );
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me to my target</p>
</div>
 
<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p>Drop here</p>
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I have only one div for dropping it's working, but I have an hierarchy of them...

Answer (score 0):

You are only one div on your container. remove container and try

```
<div class="innerDiv" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragenter="dragenter(event)" ondragleave="dragleave(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div class="innerDiv" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragenter="dragenter(event)" ondragleave="dragleave(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

.innerDiv {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: It's just a demonstration.. In my real application it is not possible

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody,

eventually, I solved it by checking if the event coords are in the outer div.